# NodeJS dynamic imports caching

Tags: node.js, json, dynamic-import

Having some issues with cache(I assume) when using dynamic imports with JSON files

Whenever I change a value in the jSON file it **doesn't** update in the browser(shows 'old' value)

- Took the `Date.now()` idea from [this article](https://ar.al/2021/02/22/cache-busting-in-node.js-dynamic-esm-imports/#cache-invalidation-in-esm-with-dynamic-imports) - can't seem to solve the issue

Express server (runnning with `--experimental-json-modules` flag):

```
import { dirname } from "path";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import express from "express";

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const loadJSON = async () => {
  let values = await import(
    path.join(__dirname, `values.json?update=${Date.now()}`)
  );
  return values.default;
};

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await loadJSON();
  res.send(result);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

values.json

```
{
  "value": "demo"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shows the old data"? You need to restart the server everytime you change something. Use Nodemon to do it automatically.

Comment: this beats the whole purpose .. the example here is just for demonstration. the real issue is to do hot-reload on live server which can't be stopped on any change.

Comment: How about if you read the file?
like `let data = JSON.parse(await readFile("filename.json", "utf8"));`

Comment: Yes, that's an option - but I still want to see if this way is works with to my needs..didn't get an answer so far

Answer (score 1):

Importing is intended to be used with modules and it will always cache the module after the first import.

It looks like you are trying to read a file here, so why not use the file system from node?

See here for documentation:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options

It could be something like this:

```
import { dirname } from "path";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import express from "express";
import fs from 'fs'; // added

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const loadJSON = async () => {
  // let values = await import(
  //   path.join(__dirname, `values.json?update=${Date.now()}`)
  // );

  const fileContentAsText = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'values.json'), 'utf-8'); // added
  let values = JSON.parse(fileContentAsText); // added

  return values.default;
};

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await loadJSON();
  res.send(result);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```